# A software like Openshot to edit video for free, but also possible to draw on the video?

Tags: windows, video-editing

I am looking for a free video editor such as [OpenShot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShot), but with one more possibility. For example, let's say I want to draw a circle around an object in the video. Is there any such software? Or is it possible to do it in OpenShot? I couldn't find how to do it in OpenShot.

Just remember that it is about an already recorded video. I noticed that The Windows 10's "Photos" has the possibility of drawing on the video, but unfortunately it does not have the option of how long the drawing should stay on the video and the drawing disappear automatically after a short time. It also change the video's quality! Just as an example, in the screenshot below you see the properties of the same video after I added a drawing on it using Window's Photos app. The left one is the original one and the two others are after a random drawing is added.

[image]

Plus that It just has pen/pencil drawing (you have to draw manually) and not regular circle or rectangle etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your requirement should be possible in OpenShot with the help of an installed instance of [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org). I have version 3.1.1 of OpenShot. Basically you create your shape indirectly in Inkscape and you can add it then as often as you like to your video. You could also morph (translate, scale, sheer, rotate) it as you wish.

Add a "Title" via the menu and choose any of the given examples in the following dialog. There you can choose to edit the *title* with an external program which would be Inkscape. In Inkscape you are free to do whatever you want.

The other way is to generate the circle (or whatever shape you'd like) beforehand in Inkscape and import it to OpenShot's image library. Then you can add it again to your layers.

Using OpenShot it should still be possible to control the quality of the output video.